# Web-scraping specific value from webpage to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape some data from a website, but I only need a specific value from the website to be shown in Google Sheets.

Now what I am trying is to use the `IMPORTXML` function.

The website that I am trying to get data is https://dps.psx.com.pk/company/TRG I need the price specifically i.e. Rs. 172 (or whatever it may be at a certain time) - I need only the price but if currency is showing up e.g. Rs.172 that would be fine as well

[image: Value I want in Google Sheet]
[image: The highlighted line is the value when I inspect element from website]

So far I am trying this and it only returns #N/A

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//span[@class='quote__close']")
```

Where A1 is the cell with the link in it.

From the web page I need the value 172.72 in the sheet and when I inspect element it shows what is displayed in the second screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw the image of the HTML, it seems that the value you want is put in the tag of `div`. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='quote__close']")
```

- I modified the xpath to `//div[@class='quote__close']`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342/importxml)

Comment: In addition to this is there a way to fetch the LDCP value in it too? The problem I am getting is that it is "stats_value", under "stats_label" and there are other "stats_value" which are there too. How can we differentiate?